# My animation balls doesn't cross at the middle when i change the window size

Tags: java, processing

There is two lane and each lane contain a ball...when animation starts it crosses on the middle when it's default window size. when i change the window size it doesn't cross on middle. i'm trying to solve this for last few weeks.

```java
float x = 0.4*width/8; 
float y = 0.4*height/8; 

void setup(){
    size(600,600);
    background(#C8F5F2);
    frameRate(10);
}

void draw(){

    fill(255);
    noStroke();
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(width/2, 0, width/8, height*2);  //vertical lane 
    rect(0, height/2, 2*width, height/8); //horizontal lane 

    fill(255,0,0,100);
    ellipse( width/2, x, 0.8*width/8, 0.8*width/8); //vertical ellipse

    fill(0,255,0,100);
    ellipse( y, height/2, 0.8*height/8, 0.8*height/8); //horizontal 
    //ellipse

    if(x < height - 0.4*width/8){
        x = x + width/45;
    }

    if(y < width - 0.4*height/8){
        y = y + height/20;
    }
}
```

i'm expecting my answer to be "cross the balls on middle at any window size"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the balls should cross in the middle, then they have to pass different ways in the same time.

The radii of the balls are:

```java
float radius1 = 0.4*height/8; 
float radius2 = 0.4*width/8;
```

The way of the first ball is on the x axis, from `x=radius1` to `x=width-radius1`.
The way of the second ball is on the y axis, from `y=radius2` to `y=height-radius2`.

So the "next position of the balls can be calculated by:

```java
x += (width - 2.0*radius1) / steps;
```

```java
 y += (height - 2.0*radius2) / steps;
```

where `steps` is the number of steps which should each ball do from its start to its end.

Further note, that the x axis is from the left to the right and the y axis from the top to the bottom. See the example:

```java
float x, y; 
float steps = 20.0;

void setup(){
    size(800,300);
    background(#C8F5F2);
    frameRate(10);

    x = 0.4*height/8;
    y = 0.4*width/8;
}

void draw(){

    float radius1 = 0.4*height/8; 
    float radius2 = 0.4*width/8; 

    fill(255);
    noStroke();
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(width/2, 0, width/8, height*2);  //vertical lane 
    rect(0, height/2, 2*width, height/8); //horizontal lane 

    fill(255,0,0,100);
    ellipse(x, height/2, radius1*2.0, radius1*2.0); //vertical ellipse

    fill(0,255,0,100);
    ellipse(width/2, y, radius2*2.0, radius2*2.0); //horizontal 

    if(x < width - radius1){
        x += (width - 2.0*radius1) / steps;
    }
    if(y < height - radius2){
        y += (height - 2.0*radius2) / steps;
    }
}
```

---

> .i need another thing to know and that is how to declare specific key to speed up and speed down the balls. like "Pressing the UP key results in doubling of speed and pressing the DOWN key results in halving of speed.

When a key is pressed then the [`keyPressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) is executed. Use [`keyCode`](https://processing.org/reference/keyCode.html) to evaluate if UP or down DOWN is pressed and change the `steps`:

```java
void keyPressed() {
    if (keyCode == DOWN)
        steps /= 2.0;
    else if (keyCode == UP)
        steps *= 2.0;
}
```

Comment: yes i got it..thanks a lot...i need another thing to know and that is how to declare specific key to speed up and speed down the balls. like "Pressing the UP key results in doubling of speed and pressing the DOWN key results in halving of speed."

Comment: hey, so know i'm facing a new problem...after adding keypressed whenever the speed increses the balls doesnot stop at the rightmost and bottomost wall...i've tried in many ways but no luck...

Comment: @D3athStrok3 I suggest to ask a new question. Add the code with your current attempt to the new question.